# If a complex function $f(z)=3$ everywhere on the unit circle and is analytic everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$, what would the value of $f(1/3)$ be?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am doing some practice for my complex analysis exam soon and I came across a question similar to the one I've mentioned above in my professor's practice sets, but I don't understand how to solve it. I have also tried to find anything similar on google but I can not find anything relating to something like this. Essentially, I can not understand how a function can be constant everywhere on a circle. Would that not mean it was just a constant function? And then it would *not* be constant *everywhere* on the circle?

Can anyone help me or suggest a theorem/lemma/anything that I can look at, or provide some insight on how to get an answer for this?

I think $f(1/3) = 0$ or $f(1/3)=3$ would be correct, either one of them I guess, but I am really not sure. If this question does not make sense to anyone else, then I shall email my professor for clarification. Until then, I would highly appreciate if anyone could help.

Thank you!

Comment: Try Cauchy's integral formula!

Comment: Your idea that the function would have to be constant everywhere is perfectly good. You just need to justify it with the identity theorem.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Hello, thank you for this reply! Could you clarify how the identity theorem could justify this? Also, so if it is technically a constant function, then $f(1/3)=3$ regardless, right? (If I'm understanding this correctly?)

Comment: @DouglasMolin Thank you!!

Comment: The set where $f$ and the constant function $z\mapsto3$ coincide has an accumulation point in the domain, so by the identity theorem they're equal. And yes, then $f(1/3)=3$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Ohh okay. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cauchy's integral formula

$$
f(a)={{\frac{1}{2\pi i}}\oint_{C}{\frac {f(z)}{z-a}}\,dz.\,}
$$

with $a=1/3$, $f(z)=3$, and $C$ is the unit circle

$$
f(1/3)={\frac{1}{2\pi i}}\oint_{C}{\frac {3}{z-1/3}}\,dz = 3\,.
$$

Comment: Ahh I didn't know I could use the integral formula for values of the function instead of just finding out the value of the integral, but thank you for this! I'd upvote your comment but apparently I do not have enough reputation. I still appreciate this though! Does this also mean you get the same answer for any simple closed contour C? Not necessarily just the unit circle?

Comment: @Diedre Yes, Cauchy's integral formula can be applied to all simple closed contours, as long as $a$ is inside $C$.

Comment: You may see the help center for "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)"

Comment: Ahh I see, perfect. And I have accepted the answer, thank you both for helping and for linking me to that page!